# kendo combobox selectedindex is not working

Tags: combobox, kendo-ui, selectedindex

I've created this combobox:

```Razor
 @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:180px" })
      .Name("CompanyId")
      .DataTextField("CompanyName")
      .DataValueField("CompanyId")
      .Text("")
      .SelectedIndex(0)
      .Suggest(true)
      .Events(events => events.Change("OnCompanyChange"))
      .DataSource(source =>
      {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetCompanysByCompanyID", "Company");
          });
      }))
```

Even though I've set the `SelectedIndex` to **1**, it's always **-1**.
For Comboboxfor  selectedindex is working fine but for combobox selectedindex is not working .It is not selecting first value by default even if I kept selectedindex to 0 or 1 or 2

Comment: If it's working with ComboBoxFor why change it? Something to note is the `.Name()` property will override the model binding. By that I mean if you say `ComboBoxFor(x => x.property1)` and then specify `.Name("Property2")`, the model will bind to `Property2` instead

Comment: If you have, in fact, solved this, please do come back and mark an answer... Or write an answer if it yet does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think `SelectedIndex` probably will not work if you are using a remote datasource.
Try to set your combobox's initial value after the datasource has finished requesting the data (through `Datasource.read`) at `Events.DataBound`.

Comment: Sorry but this isn't true. I'm successfully using a remote data source and `SelectedIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason you are having trouble is you set the `.Text` property to `string.Empty`. This would be overriding one or the other and in your case I believe it's replacing the value from the `SelectedIndex`.